# How to use Vuex to get API in Nuxt.js components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I really understand about Vuex system and want to handle it to manege API information.
And I tried to make small apps to test, but it didn't work.

I have used JSONplaceholder's API to test. In this time, I used [JSONplaceholder's data](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments).
First of all, I made Vuex code to get API as Typescript file its exist store folder in Nuxt.js project.

I already installed Vues in my project.
It's my first Vuex code but I'm really worried about code.
I have been searching Vuex in Japanese website, but I couldn't clearly understand.
Does anyone advise me?

```
~/store/document.ts
    import { MutationTree, ActionTree, GetterTree } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

export interface Customer {
    postId:number
    id:number
    name:string
    email:string
    body:string
}
export interface RootState{

}

export interface State{
    customers:Customer[]
}

const state=()=>{
    customers:[]
}
 
const getters: GetterTree<State, RootState> = {
    customer:(state:State)=>state.customers
}

 
const mutations:MutationTree<State>= {
    setCustomer:(state,customers:Customer[]) => (state.customers = customers)
}
 
 
const actions: ActionTree<State, RootState> ={
    getInfoCustomers:async({commit})=>{
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments");
            commit('setCustomer',response.data)
        } catch(error){
            commit('setCustomer',[])
        }
    }
}
```

Vue.file↓

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
     :headers="header"
     :items="items"
     class="elevation-1"></v-data-table>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, namespace } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import { Customer } from "~/store/document";
const Doc = namespace('document')

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue{
    @Doc.Action getInfoCustomers!:Function
    @Doc.State customers!:Customer[]
    
    headers=[
        {text:'id',value:'id'},
        {text:'name',value:'name'},
        {text:'email',value:'email'},
    ]
    items:any = []
    async created(){
        this.getInfoCustomers();
    this.items = this.customers.map((item:any)=>{
        return{
            id:item.id,
            name:item.name,
            email:item.email
        }
    })

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `commit` is not defined because you haven't declared it as a param in the function getInfoCustomers.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I edited my code from your advise.
It didn't work. Could you ask me some advise my code again,please?

Comment: If you take a look at the error messages you are getting, you will probably see that `this.getInfoCustomers` is not a function or something similar. Why? Because it's only declared in your component while you want to get the action from the store. How do you do that? You can see in the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) of Vuex that they are calling the action by writing `store.dispatch('actionA').then(() => {
  // ...
})`. And you have to export the actions in order to be able to get them from any other file.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I really try to fix my code. Thank you so much.